# How to read this data into a .json file format?

Tags: java, json, eclipse

```
private ArrayList<Double> celciusList = new ArrayList<Double>();  
private ArrayList<Double> farenList = new ArrayList<Double>();  
private ArrayList<Double> LDRlist = new ArrayList<Double>();
private ArrayList<Double> inchList = new ArrayList<Double>();
private ArrayList<Double> cmList = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

How do i possibly use this data information as my headings to print out in a .json file format?

Comment: Use a JSON (de-)serializaton framework : [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)  or [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/).

Answer (score 0):

I would use some kind of Java JSON Serializer, there a few of them out there.

- GSON
- FlexJson

Here is a simple example with FlexJson on how you could convert an object to JSON String.

```
final JSONSerializer serializer = new JSONSerializer();
final String output = serializer.transform(new ProtocolCalculatorTransformer(),ProtocolCalculation.class).exclude("*.class").deepSerialize(this);
return output;
```

Comment: Thank You for your help, yes i have tried using Jackson as the method of converting it into a .json format but it is not having it

Comment: Can you post you stacktrace?